# C1FlexGrid datagrid won't scroll rows on Windows 11 when the mouse wheel is used

Tags: vb.net, scroll, mouse, mousewheel, c1flexgrid

C1FlexGrid component is used in a vb.net windows form application. It does not vertically scroll when the mouse wheel is used on Windows 11. Same C1FlexGrid works fine on Windows 10/ Windows 7 etc.

Also on the Windows 11 PC other data grids used in windows form desktop application - Datagridview controls are scrolling when the mouse wheel is used.

Please suggest possible fixes , thanks !

Have tried - Windows 11 - Mouse Settings - Always show scrollbars
Adjusting the advanced setting mouse - increased number of rows scrolled

Comment: 1) To check if it is the component itself or something else about the project that is creating the problem on W11, if you make a new project with only the component, does it still fail? 2) Have you looked through the relevant [GrapeCity support forum](https://www.grapecity.com/forums/winforms-edition) to see if anyone has the same problem?

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for the suggestions, yes I created a new project with only the C1Flexgrid component and it still fails for mouse wheel scroll . The Datagridview works fine , so I don't have an option but to recode the project with DataGridView as very critical users need the mouse scroll to work. I did look through GrapeCity Forum before posting here , the version of the C1FlexGrid we are using is quite old.

Comment: Maybe, seeing as they are very critical users, the budget could be found to update to the latest version of the control. It could be cheaper than the cost to re-code and test.

Comment: Couldn't agree more @AndrewMorton , I did suggest a long overdue upgrade to latest version of the control to my boss but it has been denied. Also turns out this is running Windows 11 on a Mac PC and it is working with another mouse, but the user is not keen on switching devices ! sigh ...